# Teradata tpump utility

Tags: unix, teradata

Iam trying to load some data using tpump utility from Unix Console. 
The data has various datatypes viz., text, number, decimal, date.

Now, iam stuck as what should be the FORMAT type i need to specify in the tpump script. 
I went through the tpump manual, but could not decipher the FORMAT type to used. 
The data/columns are delimited by "|" symbol.

Any info/hint in using the appropriate FORMAT type would be of great help.

If this is a duplicate question, please help me with the actual question link.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: "|" as delimiter seems to indicate a delimited text format -> **FORMAT VARTEXT '|'**. Can you show an example record?

Comment: 2020|2|98 is one sample record format. 
We have other formats as well, wherein we have dates as part of the columns.

Comment: So this is VARTEXT, you must define all FIELDs as VARCHAR with an appropriate length. There will be an automatic typecast to the target datatype, if this fails you might have to add a SQL FORMAT + CAST.

Comment: Yes, it worked once casting done  to VARTEXT.